# PHP/mySQL query not inserting first and last rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a while loop in PHP which assigned values to the follow variables:

`$ptitle` `$summary` `$author` `$playlistfeedurl`

I have checked using echos that the rest of code is robust and before they are queried into the mySQL database (local host, MAMP) they are definitely the correct values\;

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO youtube_playlists (title,summary,author,playlistfeedurl) VALUES ('$ptitle','$summary','$author','$playlistfeedurl')");
```

However the first and last row are not going into the database and it is a real head scratcher for me!

Any help much appreciated.

**UPDATE**: Thanks for your answers!

@Yusif Ali: Thanks for the answer, it hasn't solved my issue but it will surely help. The output is: 111, so three of my results are inserted but the other two are not.

@Dutchie432: This worked a charm thank you so much! It is really bad luck these values were first and last: When I was looping 50 times I was only recieving 48 results in my table, so I reduced it to 5 results to see what would happen and these 2 results somewhere were 1st and 5th. I thought the fact they were first and last was significant, apparently not!

Comment: run `show create table youtube_playlists` on the mysql console and show us the output. There might also be a problem in the PHP code, so try to use some debuging, e.g. debug prints of the sql query in the while loop.

Comment: Nothing stands out as wrong in your query.  Could you post the PHP code as well?  Also try adding or die(mysql_error()) after the mysql_query() function to see if mysql is giving you any errors.

Comment: There's something wrong in your loop. Please post the loop.

Comment: add an `... or die(mysql_error())` to the end of your query call. If there's something goofy with your first/last queries, that'll abort the script and tell you why things are goofy.

Comment: Agree here, the loop may starts from 1 more than the start index (for example) and it may finishes one element before the end.

Comment: I re-added the orig. question back to the post. When the question gets resolved, you should LEAVE the orig. question so other people can benefit from the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your variables don't contain any apostrophes, and if they do, change the to doubles.

Just do this for each variable before construction the SQL statement:

```
$ptitle = str_replace("'", "''", $ptitle);
```

Comment: If this were the problem, all of the rows would be affected. As it is, only the first and last are affected, indicating a loop problem.

Comment: @Jonathan No, actually it can be one of possible problems. But the decision to use str_replace is a little strange :)

Comment: It is not necessary to affect all the rows, depending on the code and the data, that are apparently missing (not supplied).

Comment: @Karolis: Right, I didn't say it is THE problem, I said it indicates a loop problem. It's the most likely area to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mysql_error()](http://tr.php.net/manual/tr/function.mysql-error.php) function.

```
 echo mysql_query(example) or mysql_error();
```

This code require for debug. And you must use 'echo' otherwise you cannot see problem.